# Is there a Stack Exchange site for Radio frequency?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know there is an amateur radio section but I am looking for discussion more on signal processing and RF of existing cellular technologies.

Comment: There's a DSP site: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ... And there's a Physics site http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And there is a meta-stackexchange site for this kind of (not SO) questions.

Comment: Depending on the nature of your questions, you may want one of [dsp.se], [physics.se], or [ham.se]